# WebForm how to change alert box result to json result

Tags: javascript, html, json

Below is my code, when i change the alert to return and click the button, result are not shown.  Please teach me how to change alert part when i click button, it should return json result in the page. Thank you so much!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function GetLocation() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById("txtAddress").value;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            alert("Latitude: " + latitude + "\nLongitude: " + longitude);
        } else {
            alert("Request failed.")
        }
    });
};
    //-->
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean when you said 'return json result in the page'. Do you want to show JSON data in a div? or what?

Comment: like original code is click the button , alert box will show out . result will be inside the box.   But i wanna result show in the page not alert box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your HTML code looks like, so I'll give an example to show in a `div`.

```
<body>
    <button onclick="GetLocation()">Click me</button>
    <div id="resultdata"></div>
</body>
```

And to show in `resultdata`, you can use `innerHTML` like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetLocation() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById("txtAddress").value;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            //get JSON data.
            var JSONData = JSON.stringify({"Latitude": latitude, "Longitude": longitude});
            document.getElementById("resultdata").innerHTML = JSONData;
        } else {
            alert("Request failed.");
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

Hope this help.